# Remove all bound arguments from function signature?

Tags: python, function, signature, default-arguments, dynamic-typing

Say, we have a function `foo`, which takes another function `bar` as an argument and does something based on `bar`'s signature, and, sadly, throws an error when `bar` has default arguments. I want to use `foo` with functions, say, `bar1`,`bar2`,...`bar100`, all of which have default arguments. All of the aforementioned functions are from an outer library which I cannot change. There are too many `bar`s to rewrite each of them as a lambda statement. The only way is to remove all bound arguments from these functions. And there's exec, but I'm not that desperate yet.

I know there's a module called inspect in python which works with function signatures, I came up with the following code:

```
from inspect import signature
from functools import partial

def remove_default_args(func, **kwargs):
    func = partial(func, **kwargs)
    sg = signature(func)
    unbound_parameters = [p for p in sg.parameters.values() if p.default == p.empty]
    func.__signature__ = sg.replace(parameters=unbound_parameters)
    return func
```

Is there any better way to do this, without inspect? I ask since I know `inspect` is generally frowned upon, as it only changes the metadata.

Comment: Check out inspect's docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default argument values are stored in the `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__` attributes, which are writable. You can simply set them "back" to `None` to remove all defaults.

```
>>> def foo(x=3, *, y=5):
...    pass
...
>>> foo()
>>> foo.__defaults__, foo.__kwdefaults__
((3,), {'y': 5})
>>> foo.__defaults__ = None
>>> foo.__kwdefaults__ = None
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Comment: May be better to use `None` instead of empty tuple.  Also note that `__kwdefaults__` has keyword-only defaults.

Comment: Ah, I don't think I every looked at the value of `__defaults__` for a function that never had any default argument values; I just assumed it was always a tuple, but I see that it is `None` in that case.